# Test fails with FileNotFound while normal execution works

Tags: python, intellij-idea, python-unittest

Using Intellij with Python plugin I'm writing some code. I have some classes, modules, packages. Now I decided to go for tests.
In package I've created directory "tests" and put my test_*.py files. Structure seems to be typical:

```
Project/
|-- config/
|   |-- config.yaml
|
|-- bin/
|   |-- tests/
|   |   |-- test_one.py
|   |-- __init__.py
|   |-- one.py
|
|-- lib/
|   |-- tests/
|   |   |-- test_two.py
|   |-- __init__.py
|   |-- two.py
|
|-- main.py
|-- setup.py
|-- README
```

When I run main.py (from IDE) or run any other file as a module (manually from command line with -m switch and full path) I have no problems. But if I run tests from test folder (using
context menu in Intellij) i run into *FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'config/config.yaml'* (the module one.py is trying to read config.yaml). This is probably related to python path. How to set up IDE or project to solve the problem?

Comment: In addition to changing Intellij setup you can try to modify `sys.path()` in the test module. For example execute sys.path.insert(1, "path/to/Project/config").